# What is [keys[i]] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm reading the book Understanding EMCAScript 6 and I came across a strange line that I can't decipher.  `result[keys[i]] = object[keys[i]];`

I know that `...keys` is a rest parameter. However I can access a rest parameter using standard array syntax, for example `keys[i]`.  What does `[keys[i]]` mean?  I googled and I can't find anything.  It looks like an array but I'm not sure what type of array or how it works.  Just knowing the name would be a huge help.  It's from this code.

```
function pick(object, ...keys) {
    let result = Object.create(null);
    for (let i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
        result[keys[i]] = object[keys[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in the answer, I've never seen array keys wrapped like that.

Comment: um bracket notation with an array referencing the index

Comment: It just means that the expression `keys[i]` is used as the property name in `result[…]`.

Comment: Bracket notation isn't unique to arrays. All objects can use it as a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: It's also not new to ES6. JavaScript always worked like this. You can put any expression inside the brackets (`result[...]`). `keys[i]` is an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no magic, just nested property access using bracket notation.

```
result[ keys[i] ] = object[ keys[i] ];
```

could also be written

```
const key = keys[i];
result[key] = object[key];
```

Comment: Fascinating!  So `result[keys[i]]` is another way to say `result.keys[i]`.  It's the property name.  (mind blown!)

Comment: @DR01D [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: @DR01D: That's not right. I think you are making it more complicated than it is. `result[...]` and `keys[...]` mean exactly the same thing. `...` can be any arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this function, you have to understand that, in JavaScript **objects are just hashes.** `object.foo` is just syntactic sugar for `object["foo"]`.

This means that you can dynamically get and set object properties, which is what this function is doing.

The `keys` value is an array of the arguments passed to the function. Therefore,  the `for` loop iterates over every value in `keys`.

- The expression `keys[i]` means *i*th element of `keys`.
- The expression `object[key]` means the *property* of the object named `key`. For example, if `key = "foo"`, then writing `object[key]` is the same as writing `object.foo`.

This means that the `for` loop in the function:

- Looks up the object property matching the given argument;
- Creates a new property in `result` with the same name, and assigns the value of the property to it

Therefore, the `pick` function can be used to select certain attributes from an object:

```
pick({x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}, "x", "z") // -> {x: 1, z: 3}
```

Comment: @4castle Oh, you're right. I got rest parameters and `arguments` mixed up. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you for deconstructing that function.  I'm using your explanation to take it apart and put it back together.  Holy smokes!  That one was tough but your explanation is spot on.

Comment: @DR01D I should probably mention that arrays are just objects as well, but some of their attributes are numbers, which means that you can only access them using the `[]` notation.